# User Controls not working for image loop

Tags: javascript

i have tried it within the loop function but it says the function isn't being used so i put it outside still doesnt work and i dont know how to fix it as i thought that would work, rmember first day on javascript, thanks for the help in advance and please no jquery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #PictureContainer {
                height: 300px;
                width: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #SliderWrapper {
                width: 628px;
                height: 300px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #image {
                height: 300px;
                width: 500px;
            }

            #Next {
                float: right;
            }

            #Before {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="SliderWrapper">
            <a href="#" onclick="Forward(); return false;"><img id="Next" src="Forward.png" alt="Forward"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="Back(); return false;"><img id="Before" src="Back.png" alt="Back"></a>
            <div id="PictureContainer">
                <img id="image" src="html.png" alt="HTML">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            var i = 1;

            function loop() {
                i = i+1;
                    if(i == 5){
                        i = 1;
                    }
                if (i == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "html.png";
                } else if(i == 2) {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "css3.png";
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "WebdevLogo's.jpg";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = "WebdevLogo's.jpg";
                }


            }
                var pictureloop = setInterval(loop, 3000);

            function Forward() {
                if(i == 5) {
                    i = 1;
                } else {
                    i = i+1;
                }
            }

            function Back() {
                if(i == 1) {
                    i = 4;
                } else {
                    i = -1;
                }
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: the function forward and back don't work as they should, they're supposed to make the loop go back and forward one picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function called loop, but you never call it, so it's never changing the source attribute of the image. In the forward and back functions, add a call to the loop function at the end. There are also a few problems internally with Back() that I've fixed.

```
    function Forward() {
            if(i == 5) {
                i = 1;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
            loop();
        }

        function Back() {
            if(i == 1) {
                i = 5;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
            loop();
        }
```

Within the loop() function, consider using a [switch block](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) instead of all those else ifs. Also in the loop function, use the increment operator - i++; - which increases the value by 1, rather than the manual statement i = i+1; Also, the if i==5 statement is redundant. You already have it in your Forward function.

Comment: thanks all i had to do was put the loop() in the functions thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Do take a hard look at Sonic Soul's answer. It's good. In the meantime, if you could accept my answer, that would be great.

Comment: it works but instead of going 1 picture forward or back it goes 2 i guess its something to do with the loop running at the same time?

Comment: Inside your loop function, you need to remove the first few lines:   i = i+1;
                    if(i == 5){
                        i = 1;
                    }  
Those lines are increasing the value of i, but you've already done it in the Forward and Back functions.

Comment: thank you soo much for your help it works just like i want it to

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience i know why it wont loop now but i want it to loop and have the option for the user controlls but it will still loop? sorry

Comment: I believe you want to change this line: var pictureloop = setInterval(loop, 3000); into just setInterval(forward, 3000);

Answer (score 1):

this is more of a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but here are a few things that would make this code cleaner.

instead of duplicating image setting code, declare an array of images.

```
var images = ['img1.png','img2.png'];
var currentImage = 0;

function forward() {
  currentImage++;
  if (currentImage > images.length-1) currentImage == 0;
  setImage()
}

function setImage() {
  document.getElementById('image').src = images[currentImage];
}

setInterval(forward, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help although i haven't used what you said thanks for trying as i don't really understand to much of that.

Comment: the only difference is an added array. otherwise it's same as your code "currentImage" took place of "i"..